# Why does Murdock ask for directions to Berlin?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, the-a-team-2010

In the A-Team movie, the A-Team are heading to Frankfurt in a plane with a tank and are shot down. After emerging in the tank from a lake, Murdock asks a local for directions to Berlin. Why not to Frankfurt? Is this some sort of humourous WW2 reference that I just missed or what?

Comment: Interestingly in the German dub he actually asks for Frankfurt if I remember correctly, which is unfortunate, since seeing this question (and checking the transcript) I agree that this seems to be a nice WWII joke based on the fact that they're rolling out of a lake in a tank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is a war joke, just like this one. Why Berlin? Because it was the capital city.

[image]

Comment: Thats actually pretty funny ;)

Comment: You can also add that Murdoch was the funniest one in group and he was pretending to be US tank crew of WW2.